# how can generic types transmited from spring mobile to spring mvc server?

Tags: java, generics, spring-mvc

i have a problem with my communication between android app and java server using spring mobile on my phone and
spring mvc 3.

i want to transmit some generic data to the server and back.

after i send data from the client the app crashes with the exception 415: unsupported media type.

my server implementation looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/restclient/dosomething", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody Container<A, B, C> getRestTasks(@RequestBody Container<A, B, C> container){

//do something with container

return container;

}
```

my client looks like this:

```
public <T> T get(Class<T> gen, String url, Object obj) {

  HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
  requestHeaders.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

  // Create a new RestTemplate instance
  RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
  List<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor> interceptors = new ArrayList<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor>();
  ClientSessionHttpRequestInterceptor interceptor = new ClientSessionHttpRequestInterceptor();

  interceptors.add(interceptor);
  restTemplate.setInterceptors( interceptors);

  restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter());


  return gen.cast(restTemplate.postForObject(url, obj, gen));

 }
```

the get Method is called like this:

```
Container<A, B, C> prototype = new Container<X, Y, Z>();

Container<X, Y, Z> container= get(Container.class, url, prototype);
```

X is subclass of A
Y is subclass of B
Z is subclass of C

i think during the serialization (MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter) typeinformation get lost.

tracing the request with wireshark i found out that the type of X, Y, Z were set to object...

i have no idea to solve this problem...

i would appreciate any usefull ideas, and sorry for my english ;-)!

Thanks a lot,
zix

Answer (score 0):

This is due to [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) and as part of the spec:

> Replace all type parameters in generic types with their bounds or Object if the type  - parameters are unbounded. The produced bytecode, therefore, contains only ordinary classes, interfaces, and methods.

If you wish to save the type information for runtime, you can use a [`TypeLiteral`](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/inject/TypeLiteral.html)